# Prove the positive definiteness of Hilbert matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, positive-definite

This is so called Hilbert matrix which is known as a poorly conditioned matrix. 
$$
A =        \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & ... & \frac{1}{n} \\
        \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & ... & \frac{1}{n + 1} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n + 1} & \frac{1}{n + 2} & ... & \frac{1}{2n - 1} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

The task is to prove that matrix **A** is positively definite.

A possible way to go is to look at the scalar product:

$$(f, g) = \int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$$

within the space of polynomials of degree not higher than $(n - 1)$. There our form $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is bilinear, symmetric and positively defined thus our polynomials' space with that form is, in fact, an euclidean space of degree $n$.

Now let's take the following basis: ${1, x, x^2, ..., x^\left(n - 1\right)}$. It's easy to see that matrix **A** is a Gram matrix for this basis.

But is there another approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $X=(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq n} \in \cal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{R}).$  We have
$$
{}^tXAX=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\frac{x_ix_j}{i+j-1}=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}x_ix_j\int_0^1t^{i+j-2}dt=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_it^{i-1}\right)^2dt>0
$$ for $X\neq0$, giving the announced result since $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please say what does the t stand for?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure. $t$ is just a dummy variable to obtain $\frac1{i+j-1}=\int_0^1t^{i+j-2}dt$.

Comment: Isn't this the same approach as in the question?

Comment: Maybe it's just that the OP had not found a simple answer as the one given above.

Answer (score 6):

Let $H_n$ be the n-th order Hilbert matrix. To prove $H_n$ is positive defined, it suffices to show all the principal minor determinant of $H_n$ are positive. Say, $\det(H_m)>0$ for all $0\leq m\leq n$. This is true by the properties of Hilbert matrix. (see [Hilbert Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix)).