# Is the matrix $a_{ij} = \frac{1}{i+j-1}$ Positive Definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have a matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ defined as 
$$a_{ij} = \frac{1}{i+j-1}$$
Where $a_{ij}$ is the $i^{th}$ row, $j^{th}$ column element of the matrix. So, $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$.
Is this matrix, Positive Definite or Positive Semi-Definite? How to prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754729/59379)

Comment: Say that $i,j \geq 1$