# How can I prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_ia_j}{i+j-1}$ is never negative for any set of n real numbers $a_i$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I can't figure this out, can someone help me prove it? I know you guys will come up with an incredibly elegant solution

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you tried the $n=2, 3 $ cases?

Comment: Yes, I tried some particular cases, what gives me trouble is the fact that I can't really know anything about the numbers,

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754729/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the positive definiteness of Hilbert matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754729/prove-the-positive-definiteness-of-hilbert-matrix)

Comment: Yes got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Since $\dfrac{1}{i+j-1} = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{i+j-2}\,dx$, we have $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\dfrac{a_ia_j}{i+j-1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}a_ia_jx^{i+j-2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_ix^{i-1} \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_jx^{j-1}\,dx$$

Can you see why this is non-negative?

Comment: (The limits of summation are slightly off. I believe that's on OP rather than you.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I got it but I don't get why the last thing is non-negative.

Comment: Because inside the integral the two sums are identical.