# Determinant of certain symmetric matrices

Tags: determinant, computational-mathematics

I recently came across the following question posed by a friend. Let $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ be a positive integer and consider the $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ matrix defined as

$$ A_k=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{3} & \dots & \dots & \frac{1}{2k+1}\\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \dots & \dots & \frac{1}{2k+1} & \frac{1}{2k+3}\\
\frac{1}{5} & \dots &\frac{1}{2k+1}& \frac{1}{2k+3} &\frac{1}{2k+5}\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\frac{1}{2k+1} & \dots & \dots &\dots & \frac{1}{4k+1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

For instance,
$$A_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{3}\\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5}\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$ A_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5}\\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{7}\\
\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{7}& \frac{1}{9}\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$ A_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{7}\\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{9}\\
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{7}& \frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{11}\\
\frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{9}& \frac{1}{11}& \frac{1}{13}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

My question is: **Can we show all the matrices have non-zero determination for all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$?**

A brute force computation shows that $\det(A_k)\neq0$ for $k=1,2,3,4$. Is there a simpler and smarter way for computing $\det(A_k)$ for a generic $k?$. In addition, looking at small values of $k$, it seems that $\det(A_k)>\det(A_{k+1})$. Is
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \det(A_k)=0\,?$$

Comment: Is this of any use .... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754729/prove-the-positive-definiteness-of-hilbert-matrix