# How to prove the $n\times n$ matrix $A=\big(\frac{1}{i+j+1}\big)_{i,j\in [n]}$ is positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, schur-complement

We've been trying to show that the matrix
$$A=\Big(\frac{1}{i+j+1}\Big)_{i,j\in [n]}$$
is positive semi-definite. We've tried induction on $n$ using the Schur complement, but there is no simple analytic way to find $A_{n-1}^{-1}$ for every $n$.

Any advice?

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is positive semidefinite if for every $n \times 1$ vector $\mathbf{x}$, we have $$ \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x} \geq 0. $$

Comment: Also a special case of [Showing that $(A_{ij})=\left(\frac1{1+x_i+x_j}\right)$ is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/313249/42969).

Comment: Also: [Prove the positive definiteness of Hilbert matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754729/42969).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is  a quick proof: $\sum_{j,k} c_j \overline {c_k} x^{j+k} =|\sum_j c_jx^{j}|^{2} \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Integrate this from $0$ to $1$ to get $\sum_{j,k} c_j \overline {c_k} \frac 1 {j+k+1} \geq 0$ for any finite set of  complex numbers $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$.

$\int_0^{1} x^{j+k}dx=\frac 1 {j+k+1}$.

Comment: With integrate 'this' you mean if you calculate
$\big(\sum_j c_j \int_0^1 x^j dx\big)^2$, right? And then that is equal to $\sum_{j,k} c_j c_k x^{j+k}$ implying $x^TAx\geq 0 \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You integrate  the double sum directly without re-writing it as  modulus square. @Britta

Answer (score 2):

This is a Gram matrix with strong analogy to the Hilbert matrix. Just consider $\int_0^1 x^{j+i} dx$ for each component.  Positive semidefinitenes follows.

For a different interpretation, consider uniform rv $U$in $(0,1)$ and random vector $\mathbf x$ whose kth component is $x_k = U^k$. Then your matrix is given by $\mathbb E\big[\mathbf x \mathbf x^T\big]$ which is of course positive semidefinite by a standard quadratic form argument

**addendum**:
the most slick proof of the positive semidefiniteness comes from the fact that trace and expectation commute, so for any $ v \in \mathbb R^n$

$ v^T \mathbb E\big[\mathbf x \mathbf x^T\big] v$
$=\text{trace}\Big(v^T \mathbb E\big[\mathbf x \mathbf x^T\big]v\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big( \mathbb E\big[\mathbf x \mathbf x^T\big]vv^T\Big)$
$=\text{trace}\Big( \mathbb E\big[\mathbf x \mathbf x^T v v^T\big]\Big)$
$=\mathbb E\Big[ \text{trace}\big(\mathbf x \mathbf x^T vv^T\big)\Big]$
$=\mathbb E\Big[ \text{trace}\big( v^T \mathbf x \mathbf x^T v\big)\Big]$
$=\mathbb E\Big[\big( v^T\mathbf x\big)^2\big)\Big]$
$\geq 0$
because $\big( v^T\mathbf x\big)^2\geq 0$ and so its expecation is non-negative as well.